# Install BPL with components implemented in an other BPL in

Tags: c++, delphi, components, c++builder

I am using C++ Builder 10 Seattle and i am trying to install a component package which registers components that are implemented in a different bpl.

Technically i have done this:

I created two packages. One is defined as runtime only (comps.bpl), the other is for design time (compsIDE.bpl). All components I implemented my self are contained in the runtime lib. In the package for design time I included the fcomps.bpi and add a Unit called compsreg.cpp. In the Unit I use the following code to install components from comps.lib:

```
#include "MyComponent.h"

namespace comps
{
    void __fastcall PACKAGE Register()
    {
        TComponentClass classes[1] = {__classid(TMyComponent)};
        RegisterComponents("MyComponents", classes, 0);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the components doesn't get installed. I use the same technique for Delphi units, which are also included in the comps.bpl and they get installed.

Has anybody an idea why the Register method don't register the components? I think the only reason can be that the method never gets called for C++ but for Delphi...

Hoping for your help...
Kerem

Comment: I don't use C++Builder a lot, but could it be that the Register function should not be inside the namespace or that the namespace must have a different name? For simple debugging, add a ShowMessage() to the function that indicates it is called.

Comment: Yes, the namespace looks wrong to me

Comment: Pardon my naivete, but what is the meaning of BPL?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, Borland's proprietary shared object format, a "package".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: A BPL is just a DLL with built-in VCL support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> add a Unit called compsreg.cpp

This is the root of the problem.  The `namespace` in the file MUST match the filename, otherwise the IDE will not be able to find the exported `Register()` function correctly.  You need to change `namespace comps` to `namespace compsreg` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! I know that the IDE creates this part of code with the right namespace, when creating a new component. But I would like to know if this is documented anywhere?

Comment: Plenty of documentation, but it's all geared towards Delphi, there is no mention of this namespace limitation in C++, except maybe in third-party component writer references.  You just have to remember that Delphi unit names get translated into C++ namespaces.

Comment: I didn't know this. Thank you again.